# Depth issues with multiple instances of a movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm creating an XML custom card game and am at the point of building the deck and making them draggable so the user can drag and drop them on top of another card.

I have figured out how to build the deck and put multiple instances of the movie clip that resides in the library, I just cannot figure out a way to make each one of the cards draggable. What currently is happening is the card on top of the deck is the only one that will drag, even if I click on the card below it. I have researched `setChildIndex()`, but I don't think I am using it correctly.

Another issue I'm having is when the user clicks the click_btn (named for testing only) to build the deck it takes a while to build it, can that be sped up any?

Then once the user clicks the first card to drag it there is another long wait?

Document Class (CardGame.as)

```
package library
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class CardGame extends Sprite
{
    /*
    *   variables
    */
    private var _xml:XML;
    private var _loader:URLLoader;
    private var cardArray:Array;
    private var activity:Activity;
    /*
    *   constructor
    */
    public function CardGame():void
    {
        _loader = new URLLoader();             
        _loader.addEventListene(Event.COMPLETE,buildArray);             
        _loader.load(new URLRequest("library/card.xml"));
        click_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buildDeck);
    }
    /*
    *   metohods
    */
    public function buildArray(e:Event):Array
    {
        cardArray = new Array();  
        _xml = new XML(_loader.data);
        for(var i=0;i<_xml.card.length();i++)
        {
            if(_xml.card.face[i]=="activity")
            {
                cardArray.push({id:_xml.card.id[i],face:_xml.card.face[i],category:_xml.card.category[i],point:_xml.card.point[i],value:_xml.card.value[i]});
            }
            else if(_xml.card.face[i]=="event")
            {
                cardArray.push({id:_xml.card.id[i],face:_xml.card.face[i],category:_xml.card.category[i],point:_xml.card.point[i],value:_xml.card.value[i]});
            }
            else
            {
                trace("no card found");
            }
        }
        return cardArray;
    }
    public function buildDeck(e:Event):void
    {
        for(var i=0;i<cardArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(cardArray[i].face == "activity")
            {
                activity = new Activity();
                activity.x = 200;
                activity.y = 150;
                activity.id = i;
                activity.name = "b"+i;
                activity.buttonMode = true;
                stage.addChild(activity);
                activity.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragStart);
                activity.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dragStop);
            }
        }
    }
    public function dragStart(e:Event):void
    {
        activity.parent.setChildIndex(activity, numChildren - 1);
        activity.startDrag();
    }
    public function dragStop(e:Event):void
    {
        this.stopDrag();
    }
}
}
```

card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<cardgame>
    <card> 
            <id>1</id>   
            <face>activity</face>
       <catagory>Task</catagory>
            <point>2</point>     
            <value>Change the rule.</value>
    </card>
    <card> 
            <id>21</id>   
            <face>event</face>
       <catagory>Injury</catagory>
            <point>-2</point>     
            <value>Injury due to animal/snake/insect bite-count 3.</value>
    </card>
</cardgame>
```

The xml file actually has 64 activity card entries and 41 event card entries, but I trimmed it down to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the variable activity to the correct target. An easy fix is to set it in the dragStart method. This will ensure that you always drag the correct card.

```
activity = e.target as Activity;
```

---

```
public function dragStart(e:Event):void
{
    activity = e.target as Activity;
    activity.parent.setChildIndex(activity, numChildren - 1);
    activity.startDrag(false);
}
```

---

About your other question, I dont think that it should take such a long time parsing the XML and creating the instances. Maybe some of your methods are causing the delay. Or maybe there are heavy graphics that you could optimize.

---

**EDIT: This code makes the sorting work for me. Hope it helps.**

---

Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class CardGame extends Sprite
    {
        /*
        *   variables
        */
        private var _xml:XML;
        private var _loader:URLLoader;
        private var _cardArray:Array;
        private var _activity : Activity;
        /*
        *   constructor
        */
        public function CardGame()
        {
            _loader = new URLLoader();             
            _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, buildArray);             
            _loader.load(new URLRequest("cards.xml"));
            //click_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buildDeck);
        }
        /*
        *   metohods
        */
        public function buildArray(e:Event) : void
        {
            _cardArray = new Array();  
            _xml = new XML(_loader.data);

            for(var i=0;i<_xml.card.length();i++)
            {
                if(_xml.card.face[i]=="activity")
                {
                    _cardArray.push({id:_xml.card.id[i],face:_xml.card.face[i],category:_xml.card.category[i],point:_xml.card.point[i],value:_xml.card.value[i]});
                }
                else if(_xml.card.face[i]=="event")
                {
                    _cardArray.push({id:_xml.card.id[i],face:_xml.card.face[i],category:_xml.card.category[i],point:_xml.card.point[i],value:_xml.card.value[i]});
                }
                else
                {
                    trace("no card found");
                }
            }

            buildDeck(null);
        }

        public function buildDeck(e:Event):void
        {
            for(var i=0 ; i < _cardArray.length ; i++)
            {
                if(_cardArray[i].face == "activity")
                {
                    _activity = new Activity();
                    _activity.x = 200;
                    _activity.y = 150;
                    _activity.id = i;
                    _activity.name = "b"+i;
                    _activity.buttonMode = true;
                    addChild(_activity);
                    _activity.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragStart);
                    _activity.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dragStop);
                }
            }
        }
        public function dragStart(e:Event):void
        {
            _activity = e.target as Activity;
            _activity.parent.setChildIndex(_activity, numChildren - 1);
            _activity.startDrag(false);
        }
        public function dragStop(e:Event):void
        {
            this.stopDrag();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Activity.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Activity extends Sprite
    {

        private var _id : int;

        public function Activity()
        {
            super();

            with(graphics)
            {
                lineStyle(0, 0xFF0000, 1);
                beginFill(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF, 1.0);
                drawRect(0, 0, 80, 100);
            }
        }


        public function get id():int
        {
            return _id;
        }

        public function set id(value:int):void
        {
            _id = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @ Mattias, the dragging now works great:-) The only issue I have is the card I'm dragging appears behind the others. Is there a way for it to appear above all other cards when being dragged? Thanks

Comment: Also Mattias, you are correct about the graphic being to heavy. I created a simple box and used it in it's place and there was no hesitation, excellent idea :-)

Comment: I dont have that problem at all when I execute your code. I did have to change some things to get your code to work though. I will post my code so you can try it out.

Comment: @ Mattias, very nice work! I really appreciate your time and knowledge on this. This part of my project works flawless now :-) Also, what I figured out about the stacking order issue was `stage.addChild(_activity)` should of been `addChild(_activity)`. Removing stage solved my issue.